# SSO Integration with SonarQube from Atlassian Crowd

Tags: sonarqube, single-sign-on, atlassian-crowd

My Environment:-
Sonarqube Version: 5.6.7(LTS) 
Sonar Crowd Plugin: 2.0
Crowd Version: 3.2

Currently through our Atlassian Crowd AD based centralized login is working perfectly with our SonarQube application. However I am  looking for the way to enable SSO(Single Sign On).

Could you please someone assist me with the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at the [HTTP headers authentication](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/HTTP+headers+authentication).
To use this feature, you'll need to upgrade to latest LTS : 6.7.